# Как подключить новый git hub к visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, visual-studio-code

сейчас смотрю курсы по javascript-у и дошел до того момента когда требуется подключить github к visual studio code. В уроке лектор просто скопировал команды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в "новой" же версии гитхаба - такого нету:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело не в "новой версии" гитхаба. Эта подсказка только для пустых репозиториев показывается, а у вас не пустой - ридми лежит.

Comment: Точно сказано, сам заметил когда создавал новый репозиторий без никаких файлов. Ну что-ж, взгяд новичка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно кликнуть на кнопке Code, там выпадет список и там будут возможности клонирования репозитория. Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай уточню - в выпадающем списке будет только адрес репозитория для клонирования. Вам же потребуется написать git remote add origin *адрес*